# Openbox and xfce4-power-manager

Tags: unity, gnome, power-management, xfce, openbox

I am using Ubuntu and openbox. When I start up, I see the normal login screen like when using unity and it connects to Wifi. I have selected openbox from the dropdown list and it remembers this choice.

When I run xfce4-power-manager, nothing happens.

When I start xscreensaver-demo, I get a message that gnome screensaver daemon is already running.

There also appears to be a compositing program running.

I think the xfce4-power-manager issue is because something is already running to manage power from the Unity log in screen? I'm not sure how to verify this/change it?

Also, how can I stop the other default unity stuff starting up and ruining my system?